# Summarizing attributes across sequences in a single sequence object?

Tags: r, traminer

I'm using `TraMineR` to analyze sets of sequences. Each coherent set of sequences may contain 100 work processes from a single project for a single period of time. Using `TraMineR` I can easily calculate descriptive statistics for each sequence, however I'm more interested in descriptive statistics of the sequence object itself - subsuming all the smaller sequences within.

For example, to get state frequencies, I run:

```
seqstatd(sequences.sts)
```

However, this gives me the state frequencies *for each sequence* within my sequence object. I want to access the frequencies of states across all sequences inside of my sequence object. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your question since `seqstatd()` returns the cross-sectional frequencies at each successive position, and NOT the state frequencies for each sequence. The latter is returned by `seqistatd()`.

Assuming you refer to the outcome of `seqistatd()` you would get the mean time spent in each state with `seqmeant(sequence.sts)`.

For other summaries you can use the  `apply` function. For instance, you get the variance of the time spent in each state with

```
tab <- seqistatd(mvad.seq)
vart <- apply(tab,2,var)
head(vart)
```

Hope this helps.